# Workbox precaching: do not fail if some URLs fail

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to generate SW using the next code with workbox and gulp

```
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', () => {
    return workbox.generateSW({
        globDirectory: root,
        globPatterns: [
          '**/!(*.map|*.html|*.txt|*.orig)'
        ],
        swDest: `${root}/javascripts/sw/sw.js`,
        clientsClaim: true,
        skipWaiting: true
    }).then(({warnings, count, size}) => {
        //In case there are any warnings from workbox-build, log them.
        for (const warning of warnings) {
            console.warn(warning);
        }
        console.info(`Service worker generation completed.Count: ${count}, size: ${size}`);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Service worker generation failed:', error);
    });
});
```

The service worker is generated. However, if during install one of the URLs fails then the whole install process fails and the new service worker is not activated. Is it possible to ignore fetch failures and just continue with the precache of rest URLs?